# IIS two domains one website with query redirect

Tags: redirect, iis

I have problem with redirection on my IIS. I have two domains in Bindings to one website, and I have redirect example1.com to example.com but I want to redirect query too

What i Have:

```
main domain: example.com 
example1.com => example.com - this work
```

But what I want:

```
example1.com/test => example.com/test - this not working
```

What I'm trying:

```
        <rule name="Rewrite domain requests" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*example1.com/([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="example.com/={R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```

Second try:

```
    <rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="https://example.com/" />
    </rewriteMaps>
<rules>
    <rule name="Przekierowanie" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)example1.com/(.*)/" ignoreCase="false" />
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

How i can do this?

Comment: Why do you use `Rewrite` as action type, when your intention is "redirect"?

Comment: I'm trying Redirect too but not working

Comment: Then why do you use `=` in `url` of `action`? Also `pattern` of the condition is wrong, as HTTP Host header does not contain anything except the domain name. Use developer tools of your browser to study the request, and then you should have better understanding of the concepts.

Comment: Ok, but can u help me? I edited my question